# How to get coroutine scope in lower level manager class

Tags: kotlin, design-patterns, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine

I have a data manager class in one of my libraries. Until now it was working with executors and had its own executor. Now the class is being converted to coroutines.

The problem arises when the manager has to initialize the data asynchronously as in below example. In order to execute suspend function, the call to `suspendedInit` has to be wrapped in `launch`. The issue here is that the manager has no its own coroutine scope.

There are some that I am looking at and don't like:

1. passing coroutine scope into `DataManager` constructor and using it. The issue with that the the user of `DataManager` does not yet support coroutines and hence has no own scope.
2. `DataManager` implementing `CoroutineScope` and creating its own scope. This is discouraged as documented by `CoroutineScope` documentation.

What is the recommended solution to this problem?

```
    class DataManager {
        init {
            suspendedInit()
        }
        
        private suspend fun suspendedInit() = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            /* some long asynchronous operations here */
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can add a `coroutineScope` field to the `DataManager` like so:

```
private val coroutineScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)
```

then call the `suspendedInit()` from that scope.

Answer (score 5):

> DataManager implementing CoroutineScope and creating its own scope. This is discouraged as documented by CoroutineScope documentation.

If the initial `DataManager` had its own executor, it most likely also had its own lifecycle with a proper way of shutting down this executor.

In this case, it's perfectly fine to create your own `CoroutineScope` the same way you created your executor (actually it can literally be based off of your initial executor). The only case for which it's discouraged is if you don't properly handle the lifecycle of the scope:

> CoroutineScope should be declared as a property on entities with a well-defined lifecycle that are responsible for launching children coroutines.
>
> The key part of custom usage of CustomScope is cancelling it and the end of the lifecycle. The CoroutineScope.cancel extension function shall be used when the entity that was launching coroutines is no longer needed.

```kotlin
class DataManager {

    private val executor = TODO("original executor definition")
    val coroutineScope = executor.asCoroutineDispatcher()

    init {
        coroutineScope.launch {
            suspendedInit()
        }
    }

    private suspend fun suspendedInit() = ...

    fun close() {
        // executor.shutdown() // <-- not needed anymore
        coroutineScope.cancel()
    }
}
```

You can also get rid of the executor completely if you didn't need an independent pool of threads. In this case, you can initialize the scope with `CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)` (if what you want is to use the IO dispatcher for all coroutines) or `CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default)` (if you intend to launch mostly CPU-bound tasks) and use `withContext(IO)` when necessary.

Comment: I'd also recommend adding a `dispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.Default` (or `Dispatchers.IO`) constructor parameter to any class that has its own coroutine scope so that you can pass `StandardTestDispatcher(testScheduler)` from tests.